# AsyncSelect: A way to access options array? (problem with value property from v1 to v3)

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am upgrading from v1 to v3 of Select (AsyncSelect) component and have a problem with the value property. In version 1, we can define it as a simple value (or string) and in v3 we have { label: xxx, value: yyy} structure.

The problem I have is that, in my case, the value is defined in another component (a HOC) which have just the key and the logic to load options is in the component itself.

In a traditional structure, when user changes the value typing on it, I could save the value structure in internal state but when some HOC sets its value, I don't have the label value yet loaded.

The example solution in the upgrade guide (from v1 to v2) shows a simple example where the options array is accessable because it was defined earlier:

```
// options is defined here so it could be accessed in the component
// how can I simulate this in AsyncSelect? as the options array is loaded by a function (usually by a 
// FETCH promise)?
const options = [
 {name: 'John', id: 1},
 {name: 'Doe', id: 2},
]
return (
  <ReactSelect
    options={options}
    value={options.filter(({id}) => id === this.state.id)} // IN ASYNCSELECT I COULDN'T SEE OPTIONS ARRAY
    getOptionLabel={({name}) => name}
    getOptionValue={({id}) => id}
    onChange={({value}) => this.setState({id: value})}
  />
```